# Solving of a differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help to proceed next with the problem. This cannot be done by variable separable
[image]

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can try the substitution $z=x^{1-3}$.

Comment: What do u mean? z= x^3?

Comment: I would suggest to work $x(y)$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, I shoulf look for $x(y)$ instead. So, the differential equation write $$\frac{dx}{dy}=x y(x^2\sin(y^2)+1)$$ of better $$x\frac{dx}{dy}=x^2 y(x^2\sin(y^2)+1)$$ Introducing $z=x^2$, this then gives $$\frac{dz}{dy}=2zy(z\sin(y^2)+1)$$ Now, introduce $u=\frac 1z$ to get $$\frac{du}{dy}+2y u+2y\sin(y^2)=0$$ Now, introduce $t=y^2$ which leads to $$\frac{du}{dt}+ u+\sin(t)=0$$ which is extremely simple.

For sure, looking at all these steps, we could notice that it would have been faster ways to do it using $u=\frac 1{x^2}$ and $t=y^2$ but I was not able to see all of that directly. What I gave here are my real steps.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I understand your solution. But what do u mean by finding x(y) ?

Answer (score 0):

for Bernoulli differential equation $$y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^n$$you can divide by $y^n$
then you will have $$y^{-n}y'+p(x)y^{1-n}=q(x)$$then get $y^{1-n}=z$ so $z'=(1-n)y^{-n}y'$ then apply them into equation 
$$ y^{-n}y'+p(x)y^{1-n}=q(x)\\\frac{z'}{1-n}+p(x)z=q(x)\\z'+p(x)(1-n)z=(1-n)q(x)$$

Comment: I am not sure, if the equation that I asked is a Bernoulli's equation. Please tell what to substitute in my problem